# How do you allow users to dynamically create webpages in a forum with razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to create a forum type application with Razor v3 Webpages syntax and cannot figure out how to allow questions to get their own URL.  (Ex. http://example.com/questions.php?id=457).  I know how to do this with PHP, but I would like to know I this is even possible with Razor.

As a side note, I can't use a pre-existing package like PHPBB because the idea s quite different from a forum. Its more of a collaboration site.

Edit:
I am able to read a database and write the query, I am having issues with loading the page. With php I can tell the php controller the id of the question and it will show it on the page. I don't know how to do this with razor. I tried doing it with form submissions and post but that did not work.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to read the query string? How to read a database?

Comment: I am able to read a database and write the query, I am having issues with loading the page. With php I can tell the php controller the id of the question and it will show it on the page.  I don't know how to do this with razor.  I tried doing it it with form submissions and post but that did not work.

Comment: Are you using MVC or straight-up WebPages?

Comment: Right now I'm using webpages but can go to MVC if absolutely needed

Comment: Just check `Request.QueryString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look at the fundamentals of data management in Web Pages you should read [Introduction to Working with a Database in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Sites](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data). This tutorial uses UrlData instead of QueryString, but the result is the same.

Anyway, this article explains the several ways to transfer data between ASP.NET Web Pages: [Transferring Data Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages).